# Swift._ArrayBuffer._copyContents on Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, react-native

```
  "Swift._ArrayBuffer._copyContents(initializing: Swift.UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<A>) -> (Swift.IndexingIterator<Swift._ArrayBuffer<A>>, Swift.Int)", referenced from:
      generic specialization <serialized, Swift._ArrayBuffer<Swift.Int8>> of Swift._copyCollectionToContiguousArray<A where A: Swift.Collection>(A) -> Swift.ContiguousArray<A.Element> in libAlamofire.a(NetworkReachabilityManager.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I upgrade Xcode 12.5 with ios 14.5 version. and I tried to excute my app...
and I got an above problem... I don't know how to solve this problem. does anyone who solve this ???

Comment: I'm seeing this issue today, too, did you find a solution?

Comment: no...not yet :((

Comment: Did you try updating your Alamofire lib?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I had the same issue and got it resolved by removing
references to `$(TOOLCHAIN_DIR)/usr/lib/swift-5.0/$(PLATFORM_NAME)` from our project.pbxproj file as mentioned in this comment: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/31179#issuecomment-829536845.
I would also run all the clean up commands suggested there.

Comment: I did as you said. Now I got some hundreds of errors like `
Showing Recent Messages
Undefined symbol: protocol descriptor for Swift.Encodable`. What Can I do now?

Comment: I was confused about "removing references", but just removing the directory with terminal worked for me.. From /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift-5.0

Answer (score 3):

Deleting the text from project.pbxproj file is always too risky. We have an alternative solution

[image]

Comment: I did as you said. Now I got some hundreds of errors like ` Showing Recent Messages Undefined symbol: protocol descriptor for Swift.Encodable`. What Can I do now?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(TOOLCHAIN_DIR)/usr/lib/swift-5.0/$(PLATFORM_NAME)
```

removing frommy project.pbxproj file works for me.