# Cannot build ios app in debug after upgrading to xcode 12.5

Tags: ios, swift, xcode12.5

i recently upgraded xcode to 12.5 in order to test on the new ios 14.5.x unfortunately i am not able to compile my project anymore due to the following error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "Swift._ArrayBuffer._copyContents(initializing: Swift.UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<A>) -> (Swift.IndexingIterator<Swift._ArrayBuffer<A>>, Swift.Int)", referenced from:
      generic specialization <serialized, Swift._ArrayBuffer<Swift.Int8>> of Swift._copyCollectionToContiguousArray<A where A: Swift.Collection>(A) -> Swift.ContiguousArray<A.Element> in AppDelegate.o
```

It seems to be linked to the ZIPFoundation.framework that i am using within my project: if i comment out the usage of the library i can compile just fine.

I was using (happily) release 0.9.9 but even tried to upgrade to 0.9.12 (latest release) or even the latest git code from https://github.com/weichsel/ZIPFoundation with no effect

Note that i can compile in release, it is just the debug build that is failing on xcode12.5

i found other people lamenting similar issue (specially react native apps) with the new xcode [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67311980/swift-arraybuffer-copycontents-on-xcode), [here](https://github.com/meedan/react-native-share-menu/issues/123) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67367050/build-is-failing-for-older-projects-for-react-native-ios-xcode-version-12-5)

Comment: I would suggest filing a bug report on ZIPFoundation.

Comment: My downvote was because you specifically mentioned other SO threads where this is an issue, implying you know this is a duplicate.

Comment: @prieber actually i don't think it is a duplicate, i mean, the output is almost identical but the reason behind the message is unknown and the libraries involved are completely different / unrelated so most probably a fix will reside in a change / workaround that is not applicable in the other cases.

Comment: We disagree and that's fine, looks like you got some upvotes anyways.